# Angular PrimeNG Inputswitch show paragraph

Tags: angular, primeng

I am very new to all this.. I simple want to display a paragraph element when the p-inputSwitch is checked (and it to be gone again after it is checked again/false).

This is my HTML (component):

```
  <p-inputSwitch formControlName="bonus" 
                 (onChange)="clickBonusChecked($event)" 
                 onLabel="yes" 
                 offLabel="no">
   </p-inputSwitch>

   <p *ngIf="bonusChecked === true">Paragraph I want shown</p>
```

And this is my TS component:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  bonusChecked: boolean;

  constructor(){}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.bonusChecked = false;
  }

  public clickBonusChecked(e) {
   const bonusChecked = e.checked;
    if (bonusChecked) {
      console.log('jsdhck');
    }
  }
```

Anyone got any clue how to make this work? I find the PrimeNG documentation very limited..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this.
Now you make a whole new var

```
   public clickBonusChecked(e) {
   this.bonusChecked = e.checked;
    if (bonusChecked) {
      console.log('jsdhck');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `[ngModel]`

Creates a FormControl instance from a domain model and binds it to a form control element.

and use `*ngIf` to show and hide paragraph like this `*ngIf="bonusChecked"`

you can check status of `p-inputSwitch` like this

`<h3 class="first">Basic - {{bonusChecked}}</h3>`

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="first">Basic - {{bonusChecked}}</h3>


<p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="bonusChecked"
                 (onChange)="clickBonusChecked($event)" 
                 onLabel="yes" 
                 offLabel="no">
   </p-inputSwitch>

   <p *ngIf="bonusChecked">Paragraph I want shown</p>
```

**TS**

```
bonusChecked: boolean = false;

  constructor(){}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.bonusChecked = false;
  }

  public clickBonusChecked(e) {
   const bonusChecked = e.checked;
    if (bonusChecked) {
      console.log('jsdhck');
      this.bonusChecked = true;
    }
 }
```

you can edit or preview [Here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljjmje)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set bonusChecked = true inside clickBonuesChecked function

```
this.bonusChecked = e.checked;
```

I am assuming e.checked returns true or false than don't write if condition as i am checking you are just used it for console.log

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple with [(ngModel)]. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-eoqk35)

If you want it with reactive form, you need to subscribe to the change event of elements.

Here is [stackblitz reactive form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-primeng-eoqk35)